# Saving results after a for loop in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I have been trying to create a line of code to ping a range of IP addresses, in the windows command prompt, and after it finishes save the results in a text file. I am using a for loop to do the pinging, but I can't figure out how to save the results in a text file.
This is what I am using:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,64) do @ping 10.39.63.%i -w 1500 -n 1 | find "Reply"
```

I tried using the following code to save results in a text file, but it only saves the last command performed by CMD:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,64) do @ping 10.39.63.%i -w 100 -n 1 | find "Reply" >C:\Users\brymed\Desktop\test.txt
```

I want to keep it simple, so it'd be awesome to use only a line of code, but I am open to suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: See the results of a Stack Overflow search with [\[batch-file\] ping](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+ping). Hint: Better look on the search results of [\[batch-file\] ping TTL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+ping+TTL) as the string `TTL` is the only string which is not OS language dependent in output of `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe`.

Comment: BTW: See also the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)). You could use either `(@for /L %i in (1,1,64) do @%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 10.39.63.%i -w 100 -n 1 | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "TTL=") >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt"` or you use `del "%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt" 2>nul & for /L %i in (1,1,64) do @%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 10.39.63.%i -w 100 -n 1 | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "TTL=" >>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt"`.

Comment: The first solution defines with `(` left to `for` and `)` left to the redirection operator `>` a command block with just a single command line with redirecting everything output by the commands in the command block into a new output file. The second solution first deletes the output file if existing at all and next runs the loop with appending each output by `find` to the output file which is created on first output of `find` because of using redirection operator `>>`.

Comment: I used the first option and worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is not difficult using PowerShell. The $Hosts variable is a list of IP addresses to ping. The results are written to a file.

```
$Hosts = @()
foreach ($i in 1..64) { $Hosts += "10.39.63.$i" }
Test-Connection -Count 1 $hosts |
    Select-Object -Property Address,BufferSize,Latency,Status |
    Out-File -FilePath "$Env:USERPROFILE/Desktop/test.txt" -Encoding ascii
```

If you -must- run this in cmd.exe, the code can be formatted to do so.

```
pwsh.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$Hosts = @();" ^
    "foreach ($i in 1..64) { $Hosts += \"10.39.63.$i\" };" ^
    "Test-Connection -Count 1 $hosts -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |" ^
        "Select-Object -Property Address,BufferSize,Latency,Status |" ^
        "Out-File -FilePath "$Env:USERPROFILE/Desktop/test.txt" -Encoding ascii"
```

Get PowerShell Core from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: This is an answer to a different question.